# Looking for sample Permissioning code in Corda

Tags: corda

I am looking for sample Corda code (kotlin/java) for permissioning. Please let me know if you have any pointer. Thank you.

Comment: Search is what you can do on Google. You should come here to ask if you have a specific question.

Comment: Thank you for your response!

Comment: If you can expand on your question, then we might be able to give you a more specific answer !

Answer (score 2):

Corda is built on open standards, for network membership it relies on standard PKIX infrastructure for connecting public keys to identities (the identity of a node is an X.500 name). Please take a look at the [‘Network Permissioning](https://docs.corda.net/permissioning.html)’ section of the docs - you can use standard tools and procedures to manually create, sign and distribute certificates to Corda nodes.

For production deployments of Corda please plan to use Corda Enterprise - this will give you HA, DR, performance and other enterprise capabilities as well as enterprise-grade Doorman.